# How can I simulate/create a unit ramp signal by netlist or in schematic in TopSpice?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, simulation, spice

I have some circuits in schematic form. I want to see the circuits' response to a unit ramp signal but I can't out find how to implement this signal in the schematic.

I would like to know how could create this signal in netlist form for a circuit as simple as a resistor in parallel with the unit ramp source.

I´m a little stuck in how to create circuits by netlist in TopSpice and I would like to learn this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a PWL (piece-wise linear) source. You specify a list of time/voltage pairs and the source voltage or current changes linearly between the points.

You can't do a true step. Time must increase monotonically; a voltage can't have two different values at the same time.

Comment: I don't know TopSpice, but in LTSpice you could make a unit ramp (assuming that means what I think it means) by adjusting the parameters of the pulsed source.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. I tried and it works. I´m still trying to generate this kind of signal trough netlist but I´m a little bit lost, There is some reference that could help me to build circuits by netlist in TopSpice?